# WSL2 on Windows 10 - installed NVM, Node but can't install any package

Tags: ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL 2 on my Windows 10 (* Ubuntu-20.04  Running  2). I installed `nvm` and `node` on it.

nvm --version: `0.35.3`

nvm ls:

```
->     v14.11.0
default -> node (-> v14.11.0)
node -> stable (-> v14.11.0) (default)
stable -> 14.11 (-> v14.11.0) (default)
```

but then `npm install` **anything** gets stuck, for example:
`npm install @angular/cli@latest -g` shows the following:

```
[..................] - fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule @angular/cli@10.1.2 checking installable status
```

and after some time it errors out:

```
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.64.33.72:443
```

I also have Node install on Windows and it works there.
I tried to stop antivirus - this doesn't help.

Can anyone please help with this networking issue?

Comment: Did u manage to  fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue(( 
I have sent issue request there: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7254

Comment: I have the same issue ... haven't found a solution yet.